# Can I install selectively bootable Ubuntu on an external HDD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hard-drive

I would like to know if I can install Ubuntu on an external USB HDD (not a thumb-drive, but a 200GB portable drive) and then on my Mac, using the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key during the restart to then select that drive as the bootable drive and thus launch Ubuntu?

Under normal circumstances I'd do nothing at restart and would want the Mac to boot into OSX as normal, but if I pressed the <kbd>Alt</kbd>; key during restart then I would want to launch Ubuntu.

Possible? Is this simply a straightforward install onto an external HDD? Or would I need to set up GRUB or another EFI bootloader for every startup and select OSx each time I don't want to launch Ubuntu?

Comment: Nice edit Zanna! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,you can.
connect your external hard disk and go to boot setup and change boot priority to the external HDD .

Comment: Just so I understand the difference - as I just set up Xubuntu on a Macbook and did a dual boot option.

Comment: So a dual boot is where I have to select each time I restart which OS I want to boot into, and what you said can be done is not that, but is one where it will boot normally into OSx if I do nothing, but if I select 'alt' during restart then I can choose?

Comment: Also... 'boot setup' doesn't sound to me like it's a Mac thing! I have never heard of that on OSx.  I assume you meant that as instructions for Win users?